# How do I delete scsecsvc.exe which is left after the quick heal uninstall?

Tags: permissions

I installed the anti-virus - Quickheal trial version and then uninstalled it in order to install another anti-virus. Quickheal seemed to have left this program which runs in the background and simply wont die. I am on windows 7 - 32 bit. I am the sole administrator of the computer. I tried to kill the process-tree via the taskmanager. It says "operation could not be completed - access denied". I tried the `services.exe` method.

In services.exe this one is defined as CoreBrowsing Protection. On right-click I found that I do not have any option to stop the process. Neither I was able to control its auto-start options. The path to the program is `"C:\Program Files\Quick Heal\Quick Heal Total Security\ScSecSvc.exe"`.

[image]

I have googled it and could not find a solution. I also scanned the [quickheal support][2] forum but there is no mention of this problem at all. The I tried some process-killer software listed below.

I tried [process-explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) which returns the same "access-denied" message. I tried [process-hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) which was able to kill the process but then immediately returns back into the task manager.
I tried the cmd method with `taskkill /IM "scsecsvc.exe" /T /F` , again says access denied.

Could there be an alternative method which I am missing that could delete this persistent program or my only way out is to format my system ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When users here get infections like this, with executables or processes that get left behind, I usually remove them from safe mode. I'd recommend giving that a shot. Safe mode will open Windows with the bare minimum of services running, which usually allows you to remove files that have processes that won't stop running. Hope that helps!

Comment: that solved it. thnx.